# Flutter GestureDetector onTapRight & ontapLeft

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have read the flutter documentation about GestureDetector and i can only see **onTapDown &
onTapUp**

and i believe if there is **up and Down** there will be **Right and Left**

how can i achieve onTapRight and onTapLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @L.Gangemi that gave me the idea of what to use....

i solved this by this sample code

```
 onTapUp: (details) {
                                      if (details.localPosition.direction >
                                          1.0) {
                                        print('Left');
                                      }
                                      if (details.localPosition.direction <
                                          1.0) {
                                        print('Right');
                                      }
                                    },
```

Answer (score 2):

**onTapDown** & **onTapUp** do not refer to the area/position where you press, but they do refer to:

**onTapDown**: The moment your finger actually touch the screen

**onTapUp**: The moment your finger leave the screen

From the docs:

> onTapDown: A pointer that might cause a tap with a primary button has contacted the screen at a particular location.
>
> onTapUp: A pointer that will trigger a tap with a primary button has stopped
> contacting the screen at a particular location

To achieve right or left tap, you could use a `Stack` widget to overlay a `row` with 2 Gesture dector widgets.

DOCS:

[onTapDown](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTapDown.html)
[GestureTapDownCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureTapDownCallback.html)

Comment: okay thanks is there a way to give position of onTap of a widget without using stack? i dont want to use stack. what i want to achieve is if i tap the right side of a widget it should perform a function

Comment: As you can see from the docs (I'm gonna include them in the answer), the function called by onTapDown is of type GestureTapDownCallback which comes with a TapDownDetails  parameter. It should contain all the information you need to track down the tap coordinates.

Comment: i have read it but can you help me with sample code of it?